# Desktop icons and fullscreen flash apps pixelated instead of blurred

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, pixels

On my other devices, and as far as I can remember, at some point on this laptop, stretched graphics such as desktop icons, and fullscreen flash apps (such as Youtube, Vimeo) appear pixelated and jagged and no blurring or filtering is being applied to smooth them other.

See the image below or [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9XKw.png) for a snippet of a 480p youtube video set to full screen (1600x900 desktop resolution). Notice the strange jagged edges where the icons don't stretch correctly, and on the text `Change Quality`.

The laptop is an Acer 7750G which has a Radeon 6850M GPU. I've updated to the latest Catalyst drivers.

[image]

Comment: is hardware accelerating enabled? check by going on a [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ), right clicking and pressing settings.

Comment: Yes it is, but thanks for the suggestion. I get it on other things like desktop icons that are stretching, so it's not limited to flash, but this is certainly the place where it's most "in my face"

Comment: Also, I get similar distortion on the video itself, including if I force HTML5 video on youtube. Although HTML5 produces native resolution playback controls.

Comment: How old is the laptop? Do you still have warranty?

Comment: It's 6 months old, you really think it could be a hardware issue? VLC playback is perfect and 3D in games is also flawless.

Comment: I don't know. But phone up HP. https://www.google.com/webhp?q=contact+hp

Comment: It's an Acer, but I see your point ;)

Comment: Oh now I see that I actually have switchable graphics (HD 3000 integrated), perhaps I should look into the Intel drivers too.

Comment: oh right Acer then.